# Connect to Service Fabric Application

Tags: jquery, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have deployed a 5 node cluster on Azure SF with 3 applications. I have deployed my html web app with Jquery on Azure App Service , now i want to call one of application **API** hosted on cluster from my web app.
In $.ajax request what value should i pass to url property access my API?

**SF EndPoint** :https://xyz.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000

**API** :  fabric:/ApplicationAPI

My SF and App service are in same **VNet** with **load balancer** on my SF cluster

Comment: What kind of communication does your api on ASF support? Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cluster will be reachable by the public DNS entry that was created when you created the cluster.

https://xyz.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com

Now...in order for you to reach your services you need to open up the ports on the load balancer. If you specified a listening port on fabric:/ApplicationAPI/SomeService on port 8217 as an example, you would create a load balancer rule from port X to port 8217 on the backend pool. Port X would be whatever port you want to use when using the above domain name.

Note:
You could set up some sort of gateway in front of the load balancer so that you can create path based rules to forward the traffic so you're not accessing everything on weird port numbers.

Comment: I have opened the backed pool from port x to 8594, so i just have to pass this url https://xyz.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com and load balancer will redirect me to my API , please correct me if my understanding is right ?

Comment: I am assuming you changed x to an actual value?

Comment: yeah so if you opened up the load balancer to do port 5000 to port 8594 as an example...you would be able to reach your service at: https://xyz.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:5000/. Now if you have a web api set up you'd obviously still need to go to the correct route. Also if you added a path to the OWIN listener you'd need to use that as well. The load balancer will just forward the traffic appropriately.

Comment: thank you its working now , one quick question if my App Service and SF are in same Vnet is there any internal way to communicate between the applications without opening the public ports of my SF application

Comment: Unless you are using App Service *Environments* I didn't think you could actually put your App Service Plan inside your VNET. I could be wrong, though.